# conditional display of an html element, using jsp

Tags: html, jsp, conditional-statements, show

I would like to display a second password input field, based on a Boolean value, read from the database. The code to read from the database is written already, and it works. The issue I have is with conditional display of the list element. 
I know very little jsp - googled for answers, and came up with the following, witch is not working.
code:

```html
   <ul>
    <li><label for="username">Username</label>
     <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
    </li>
    <li><label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
    </li>
    <!-- conditional display of a second password field -->
    <% 
     if (@showDoublePasswords == true) { 
    %>
     <li><label for="password">Password 2</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
     </li>
     
    <% } %>
            </ul>
```

Comment: `if (@showDoublePasswords == true) { ` ..this is wrong ..variable name cannot start with a symbol... except `$` and `_`

Comment: Remove the @

You can use scriptlets as you use in your example (<% %>) or jstl tag library to perform an if. jstl is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try This

```
<ul>
                <li><label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
                </li>
                <li><label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
                </li>
                <!-- conditional display of a second password field -->
                <% 
                    //Remove '@' 
                    if (showDoublePasswords == true) 
                    { 
                %>
                      <li><label for="password">Password 2</label>
                          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
                    </li>

                <% } 
                %>
            </ul>
```

*